# Calculating the Average degree in a Directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm quite confused at the moment, as I think my analytics tool is doing something weird. Assume that I have a **directed** graph that has 281903 vertices and 1992636 edges. What is the average degree?

The tool gave me back: 14.137. But I think this is wrong since this is for an undirected graph.

Shouldn't it be 7.06? (Since you simply divide the amount of edges by the vertices?) Sorry for this newbish question.. I surprisingly couldn't find an easy explanation online...

Comment: The average in-degree and average out-degree are $7.06\ldots$.  Degree counts both directions, so the average degree is the sum of those.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each edge, there are two vertexes associated to it. So each edge adds two degrees to the graph.

Now you have $1992636$ edges, the total degree is $1992636\times 2$,and the average degree is $\frac{1992636\times 2}{281903}=14.137$.

Comment: Ah thank you very much for the explanation!!

Comment: @R. Feng how did you got `281903`?

Comment: You can change an undirected graph to a directed one by changing each udirected edge to a pair directed edges. Then by your logic the average degree doubles.

Answer (score 6):

The answer of this guy is incorrect.
For a directed graph, each edge accounts to 1 degree, and not two (as the edges grant a degree just to one vertex, and not two vertices).
Therefore, for a directed graph, the average degree is simply the number of edges divided by the number vertices.

Comment: This is confirmed by working with directed graphs in Gephi and using the statistics function.

Answer (score 2):

If $k_i$ is the degree of $i$th node, so for a network of $N$ nodes, the total degree will be equal to $\sum{k_i}$ where $i = \{1 .. N\}$. As for an undirected link between nodes $u$ and $v$ the degree is counted twice, so the total degree equals $2*$Links. Hence $k_{avg} = \frac{2L}{N}$ for an undirected network. However, for directed networks $k_{in} = k_{out} = L$ and $k_{avg} = \frac{L}{N}$.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference